# On scroll load data on demand

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am implementing on demand loading of data through scrolling.

I have register the function in `document.ready` for a div.

The data should only be populated once the scroll is reached to the last. so to identify whether the scroll has reached till the last i am using the below function.

```
$("#tree").scroll(function () {
                if (isScrolledToBottom(this)) {
                    
                }
            });
```

But the function is not returning the correct value. What I mean is it should return the a true value when scroll has reached to its last.

```
function isScrolledToBottom(object) {
            return ($(object).attr('scrollHeight') - $(object).scrollTop() - 1) <= $(object).height();
        };
```

Comment: I'm sure, there's a solution already for that. Google for `infinite ajax scrolling`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead :

```
return ($(object).attr('offsetHeight') + $(object).attr('scrollTop') >= $(object).attr('scrollHeight'));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do infinite scrolling, check out my answer here:
[How to load the web page content based on user scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020351/how-to-load-the-web-page-content-based-on-user-scrolling/5020406#5020406)

This demo is triggered at a certain Y scroll position. If you are looking to accomplish this specifically when a user reaches a certain item, you might want to look at the Waypoints plugin.

http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/

Infinite scroll Demo: http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/infinite-scroll/

```
$('.theItems:last').waypoint(function(event, direction) {
    //Ajax fetch here
});
```

Comment: Well, I believe the concept itself is a bit confusing to those to who don't grasp it. What don't you understand?

Comment: I was looking for the js that controls your infinite code example to understand how content was actually loaded and where into, just noticed it at the bottom of the page so that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var scrollHeight = $(object).prop("scrollHeight"); // total scrollable height of the element 
    var scrollTop = $(object).scrollTop(); // how far you have come from the top while scrolling vertically
    var height =  $(object).height(); // the constant height of the portion in display at all times

    if (scrollHeight === (scrollTop + height)) {
        //console.log("fetching page");
        fetchNextPage();
    }
```