# paging like facebook's main page

Tags: asp.net, scroll, paging

I have a page with news in it. I can't just fetch data and display 300+ news on my page. 
so i tried `paging` but in asp.net paging previous records are not on the page. **I want `paging` something like `facebook's` main page** where new records appears after old records. 
I surf but could not find something like that. Can anyone help me. How do i make it?

A single or a tip can be useful for me.

**Note:**
Difference is that i want the content to load when i click on a `see more news` button in the bottom.
Thanks for your response.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020351/how-to-load-the-web-page-content-based-on-user-scrolling That again has some pointers to some other questions asked on SO.

Comment: i want the content when someone click on a button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i used simple paging instead of what i want. I used two buttons for back and forth.
Cant find the solution i want.