# Which plugin is used to show the data in front end of socrata

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, plugins, socrata

Is it possible to implement the view(the table) that socrata gives to users to implement in a mvc application? Especially the scroll effect where it takes only ms to load data.
If not can anyone suggest any lightweight grid for same (scroll with faster loading)

Answer (score 1):

The scroll effect is making use of paging by loading data dynamically, rather than trying to load the entire dataset at once.

If you are using [SODA.NET](https://github.com/CityofSantaMonica/SODA.NET), the `Resource` object has a `GetRows(limit, offset)` method that you can use to retrieve paged sets of rows in the dataset.

There are any number of ways you could implement the scroll-to-load, including client-side AJAX requests. See [this answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020351/how-to-load-the-web-page-content-based-on-user-scrolling/5020406#5020406) for a starting point.