# Looking for a way to filter hundreds of elements on a page without a slow load

Tags: jquery, ajax, filtering

I used mixitup (https://mixitup.kunkalabs.com/) to filter hundreds of elements on a page, but the page is very slow to load. Here's the page: http://ohmydrifter.com/category/inspiration/

I see that mixitup says you shouldn't use it on over 150 elements. Is there a better way to go about filtering a large amount of elements? (I'm know jQuery but I'm not familiar with AJAX. Is this a situation for AJAX?)

Comment: Why don't you use that one plugin that loads content as you scroll?

Comment: I thought that would work too, but in order to filter the subcategories of posts they need to be loaded already.

Comment: Try this then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020351/how-to-load-the-web-page-content-based-on-user-scrolling