# Wordpress 25+ sec loading time

Tags: wordpress, performance

So after testing my wordpress site, its taking quite a while to just load.

http://kimztech.tk/wordpress/

I have no clue what to do and would really appreciate some help on this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0t10s.png)

^ The currently installed plugins

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: There are far too many possible reasons for this happening. Maybe your web server is really slow. Maybe your database is massive. Maybe you're running several cURL requests when loading the page. We can only guess with the information at hand. Try to disable plugins one at a time to see if that improves loading times.

Answer (score 0):

Well first you have a lot of data to show in one page. loading all the data at the same time might be making the site slow. Try loading a part of the page at first and while you scroll the page load more.

look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020351/how-to-load-the-web-page-content-based-on-user-scrolling). make some content load first then when scrolled load more item

For eg:

```
<div>display first............</div>
<div>display at scroll........</div>
<div>display at scroll........</div>
<div>display at scroll........</div>
```

Well I Hope this helps.