# How to load data while scrolling a <div>

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous

For now , I have made something like this: [tutorial @9lessons.info](http://www.9lessons.info/2009/07/load-data-while-scroll-with-jquery-php.html)

which loads data while scrolling down the window and its working fine. But I am trying to get something like: `when you scroll a div, then it loads the data.`

Please help me to figure this out or direct me to any link which has a tutorial kinda thing which explains how to do a `data download` and adds this to the DOM while you scroll the div.

Comment: I found this article (thank you Smashing Magazine) and I though that you might find this interesting! http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/scrolling/

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of possible solutions. For example you could take the `scrollTop` of your document and when that reaches the `height of the document` - `viewport height` you know you are at the bottom of your page.  That is the custom approach in teletubbie-pseudo-code. But maybe you can use a combination of [jQuery](http://jquery.com) together with [Twitter bootstrap #scrollspy](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#scrollspy).

Also I found this:
[How do I make content load when the user scrolls down to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9247907/how-do-i-make-content-load-when-the-user-scrolls-down-to-it) which has a possible duplicate referring to [How to load the web page content based on user scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020351/how-to-load-the-web-page-content-based-on-user-scrolling) which refers to [Loading content as the user scrolls down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183782/loading-content-as-the-user-scrolls-down) and [Load content as an element scrolls into view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464968/load-content-as-an-element-scrolls-into-view) and [Loading content with ajax while scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283669/loading-content-with-ajax-while-scrolling) and [Reloading new content while scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584088/reloading-new-content-while-scrolling)

Where in the comments the following links can be found:

- http://gbin1.com/technology/jquerynews/20111017jquerypluginwaypoints/infinite-scroll/
- http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload
- http://johnpolacek.github.com/scrollorama/

Maybe that can help you in some way. I am just curious, did you even try to Google it yourself?

**edit**: I found [this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/scrolling/) article on the Smashing Magazine facebook page which you might find interesting reading.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with PHP alone as the PHP on your server has absolutely no concept of what is happening within the client UI after it has served the page source.